# Comparing 2 items of an listbox and 2 lines of a Memo

Tags: delphi, listbox, memo

How to compare 2 items of an listbox and 2 lines of a Memo?
How do I give an item of an Listbox a variabele? How do I give a line of a Memo a variabele?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Please edit your question and include the code that you've tried to write.  Then ask a question specific to the code example.  You question suggests you might benefit from one of many tutorials available from Embarcadero, including http://www.embarcadero.com/firemonkey/firemonkey-e-learning-series

Answer (score 3):

#### ListBox items

The contents of a ListBox is stored in `TListBox.Items` which is of type `TStrings`. This is a zero-based list/array of strings, thus in order to get the second item in the ListBox call one of the following:

- `ListBox1.Items.Strings[1]`, or
- `ListBox1.Items[1]`, because `Strings[]` is the default property.

#### Memo lines

The contents of a Memo is stored in `TMemo.Lines` which also is of type `TStrings`, thus to get the first line of the Memo, call:

- `Memo1.Lines.Strings[0]`, or
- `Memo1.Lines[0]`.

#### Comparison/relational operators

- `=` equality
- `<>` inequality
- `<` smaller
- etc...

#### All together

Thus to compare the first line of the Memo with the second item of the ListBox, do:

```
if Memo1.Lines[0] <operator> ListBox1.Items[1] then
```

For example: when you want to check whether both are equal:

```
if Memo1.Lines[0] = ListBox1.Items[1] then
```

#### Going advanced

Maybe a simple comparison operator does not give enough information about the difference between the two strings. Then use a function instead of an operator to compare the two strings, see the units `SysUtils` and `StrUtils`. For example, when you want to compare both strings for having the same text, regardless case:

```
if SameText(Memo1.Lines[0], ListBox1.Items[1]) then
```

#### Comparing 4 items simultaneously

Concatenate two comparisons with a boolean/logic operator:

```
if (Memo1.Lines[0] = ListBox1.Items[0]) and (Memo1.Lines[1] = ListBox1.Items[1]) then
```